# How to upload data to an email using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how would I be able to use javascript/jquery to take the input of a textbox and send it to an email address, or a server?? I am not familiar with PHP or how to access a server or any of this. I only understand local storage. Could somebody please point me in the right direction??

Thanks

Comment: Upload to a temp file: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Send email with attachment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: Use input form, to send that data to server use ajax then use php to trigger a mail

Comment: Please add your form code that generates the input to your question. I assume you have access to the server file manager and can add a page if needed? This is very easy using php in your form action point to a page called mailer.php. This page would hold a few lines that would email the user then redirect them back to the form page and include a success or failure post. Or exit the code on the php page and add a button to return to the form page.

Comment: best solution in this case is .......
    https://www.smtpjs.com/